# Black screen on boot after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I was encouraged to update to 14.04 by Ubuntu, I have done so and when I try to boot up all I get is a blank black screen.
If this cannot be resolved can you please send me details how to remove Ubuntu completely as I am very disappointed with what has happened.
Luckily I still have windows on my PC and I can contact you

Comment: did ubuntu logo come???

Answer (score 0):

When grub2 appears press '`e`'.

Locate the line with

```
linux .... ro
```

and change it to

```
linux .... rw
```

it worked for me. It seems a bug on machine with double booting where ubuntu has been intsalled through Wubi